# Update duplicate records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have 2 table structure as follows,

TableA

[image]

TableB

[image]

I try to update `TableB` with the following query,

```
update tableB set ID = b.ID from tableB a inner join tableA b on a.prod = b.prod
```

[image]

`Prod a` in `TableB` is getting updated with only `ID` as `1`, although `Prod a` also has `ID`s as `2` and `3` in `TableA`.

How could we modify the `update` query to get all the `ID`s in `TableB`?

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LXYIq.png

I want the expect result as the image attached

Comment: Why do you have more rows all of a sudden? An `UPDATE` statement should not insert any additional rows.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is bring all the IDs from table A in table B for all the matching products. How could be get that done?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `MERGE` concept,

```
MERGE TableB AS T
USING TableA AS S
ON (T.ID = S.ID and T.Prod = S.Prod) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(ID, Prod) VALUES(S.ID, S.Prod)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.ID = S.ID, T.Prod = S.Prod

GO
```

You should try this,

```
Update TableB set ID = A.ID from TableA A
Inner Join TableB B on B.Prod = A.Prod And B.ID = 0
```

Comment: Above query does not seem to be answer my question. It merges tableA with tableB. What I want is to bring only IDs from tableA in tableB for matching prod

Comment: You need to be update condition according to your need, actually in TableB Id is not there default so you need to go with only Prod.

Comment: This is the good concept you can utilize in many ways, just given overview here, how you can use it.

Comment: Using MERGE for typical upserts has some issues with deadlocking. There are several other bugs with MERGE. Not saying to not use it but make sure you know the issues. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Then we can use Begin TRAN; and Rollback TRAN;

Comment: Updated query provided throws an error message as it's trying to update more than once.

Error message as follows,
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: I didn't have environment to run this query, I have updated answer based on assumption  only, try it.